# HuggingFace evaluate-cli create command results Error: "datasets[0]" must be a string

Tags: huggingface, huggingface-hub

I follow the official documentation of `evaluate 0.4.0` to **freshly** create a custom metric in an empty folder with the following command:

```
evaluate-cli create "My Metric" --module_type "metric"
```

The command returns the following error:

```
Error: "datasets[0]" must be a string
```

The command creates these files but I am unsure whether the files are intact:

```
app.py  my_metric.py  README.md  requirements.txt  tests.py
```

How to resolve this error?

using `evaluate version 0.4.0`